# Create new partition on ssd hard (remove hibernate)

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I bought Dell Vostro 3360 notebook with Windows 7

It has 128 GB SSD hard disk, it is already has 4 partitions:
Dell partition, Recovery partition, OS partition, Hibernate partition.
Here is screenshot (Russian language, but I made some marks):

[image]

I want to split OS partition, because I need c:\ and d:\ . Reason is that I have a lot of difficulties with administration mode on c:.

So I tried to split OS partition but I already have 4 partitions. Can I remove hibernate partition without consequences?  I have Hibernate disabled in settings, but I have hiberfil.sys file on  c:\

If I can remove it, how can I do this, I can't do this with standard GUI disk managment tool

Comment: `powercfg -h off` from an elevated command-prompt should delete the `hiberfil.sys` file, or you can delete it manually. I'd recommend against using Hibernate on SSD because it will reduce the life of the drive.

Answer (score 1):

Unless Dell has some specific own hibernation function which MUST use that partition (which is pretty unlikely, but if you want to know, call their support), you could delete it, because windows can use the system partition for hibernation purposes.

But are you going to use hibernation a lot? If that is the case, it is adviseable to leave partition so that you will always have space for the hibernation file (I assume the laptop is pre-configured to use it for hibernation, since that's how you got it.) You will not win anything in space, because to use the hibernation, you will need those 8GB free anyway, no matter if they are on another partition or on your c: drive.

If you however won't be using hibernation at all, or just want to remove the partition, that could be done as well, but you will have to boot up from a live-cd or usb. As far as I know, Windows cannot resize live partitions. I would suggest any recent linux live-cd with GParted, for example Ubuntu or Debian. There are also GParted-only live CDs. If you can connect the drive to another windows machine, it's possible to do in windows drive manager, but since you are on a laptop and taking out the drive and putting it into another computer seems complicated, I would stick with the live-cd/usb.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable hibernate by using `powercfg -h off`
Once it is disabled, try disk clean up and select hibernate file and clean up the file.

Once the hibernate file is deleted, try deleting the partition. 
If the partition cannot be deleted after this, you need to go to recovery options or startup repair. 
This can be achieved by two ways

1. You can find it by pressing F8 key before the windows loads
2. Try inserting the windows DVD if provided by Dell

On the screen it shows install, there will be an option to select repair your computer. 
Open command prompt from there and type `DISKPART`

After disk partitioning tool is loaded, use these commands to create a new parition.

```
DISKPART> list disk
DISKPART> select disk (id)
DISKPART> list partition
DISKPART> select partition (id)
DISKPART> format fs=ntfs label=(name) quick
DISKPART> assign letter (letter)
DISKPART> list volume
```

Once the above stages are complete, you can reboot your machine and access your drive